# Use hosted build server to build ASP.NET RC1

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have not yet upgraded our ASP.NET Core app to the final version. We're still in RC1.

Can I still use the hosted build service on VSTS to build and deplop the app? We will upgrade the app soon but in the meantime I just want to be able to test and deploy it to our test site on Azure WebApp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. But you may need to following the steps in this link to build and deploy it: [Deploy ASP.NET Core 1.0 apps to Azure web apps](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/examples/azure/aspnet-core10-azure-web-apps).

And as soon as you upgrade it to RC2, you can refer to the steps here: [Build and deploy your ASP.NET Core RC2 app to Azure](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/aspnet/aspnetcore-to-azure).